# Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 navbar not styling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, sass

I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 with Rails 5.0.1 to create a personal general template for some websites I'm building. At the moment I have a basic layout file, a homepage view file, and an import for Bootstrap in the scss (as well as a few other bits and pieces that aren't important right now).

**/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "Sites Template", '#', id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help",   '#' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb**

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>

  <h2>
    Rails page
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Call to action", '#', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo")
```

**/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I have not yet added any custom stylings, yet at present the site navbar isn't styled at all. With previous versions of Bootstrap and Rails I would have expected it to be styled with something similar to the above code (as I recall, anyway...)

[image: home page]

As you can see, Bootstrap is being required in, and the jumbotron element is being styled by Bootstrap. Is the lack of Bootstrap default navbar styling likely to be a problem with the Alpha version of Bootstrap, or with the way Rails 5 applies .scss files to the layout template as opposed to the nested templates (which is causing Bootstrap styles to skip over the layout file), or something else? I just added the Bootstrap gem to my gemfile and ran `bundle install` in the normal way. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and adapted code from an example on the Bootstrap website and it's working.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <%= link_to "Sites Template", '#', id: "logo" %>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Looks like v4.0.0-alpha6 Bootstrap requires you to explicitly invert a navbar background with `bg-inverse` rather than relying on just `navbar-inverse`. `navbar-toggleable-*` does also appear to be required now for correct horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue with your Bootstrap4 alpha6 code.  I know that going from alpha5 to alpha6, they made a number of changes to the navbar.

To quote the [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/),

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-toggleable-* for
>   responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

I believe that missing the 'navbar-toggleable-*' class is causing your nav-items to not be aligned horizontally.

To follow the example they have in their docs, your navbar code should look more like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-fixed-top bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <%= link_to "Sites Template", '#', id: "logo" %>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to "Home", '#', class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to "Help", '#', class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Note that you were missing the 'nav-item' and 'nav-link' classes

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work properly. Now the words 'site' and 'template' appear vertically and the words 'home' and 'help' are horizontally aligned, but other than that the only new styling applied is that 'home' and 'help' now appear as white on white and are thus invisible unless highlighted.

Comment: ah, missed the bg-inverse change.  As you can see, there were quite a few changes made to the navbar classes..

Answer (score 0):

If you download Bootstrap v4 alfa 6 version, it should work - just in case try to match the version of your js and css Bootstrap files along with the documentation example.

What I did was, download the source codes again from this link: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0-alpha.6/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist.zip

And used the navbar example on this page:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Good luck!